# A failed attempt to align DIV elements

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to align 3 `<div>` elements in such way that two are next to each other, and the third is under them, stretching from one to another. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yotamoo/cr8s8/) is my Fiddle for you to see. Also here's my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri903jtb93a5168/background.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-top: 19%;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

#bottom {
    position:relative
}

.lists {
    background: transparent;
    width: 268px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
</style>​
```

Any ideas? I'm new and trying to get a hold of css.

Thanks!

Comment: In the demo, is the JavaScript code relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda changed you code a bit,
I added clear:float, after the left and right div.

please take look at the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ubatof/1/edit), do let me know if thats what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

please make corrections

```
#right {
    /*  omit float: right  
    float: right; */
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

#bottom {
   /* omit position: relative  
   position:relative */
}
```

replace your code with above code and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

add style  `clear: both;` to the div whose id is 'bottom'